# Method hasMany Laravel not working in Web Hosting

Tags: laravel, methods, has-many

I have problem in my method hasMany Laravel.
 When i use in my file local, it's worked. But, when i hosting my file to web hosting it's not working. 
 I don't know what the problem, because my data can't show something. 
 I have try to solve with googling, but i can't solved it.

My Table Usulan

| Id | Title | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Service | Car Service |

My Table Usulan Service

| Id | Usulan Id | Car Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Toyota |
| 2 | 1 | Honda |

My Table Expect Result

| Id | Usulan | Usulan Service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Service | 1. Toyota 2. Toyota |

My code on blade

```
@if ($dataUsulan->jenis_form == 2)
  @foreach($dataUsulan->usulanServis as $dataServis)
       <div class="col-md-12">{{ $dataServis->merk_tipe_kendaraan.' '.$dataServis->tahun_kendaraan }}</div>
       <div class="col-md-6">Jatuh Tempo Servis</div>
  @endforeach
 @endif
```

My code  in Controller

```
UsulanAadb::join('tbl_pegawai', 'id_pegawai', 'pegawai_id')
   ->leftjoin('tbl_pegawai_jabatan', 'id_jabatan', 'jabatan_id')
   ->join('tbl_unit_kerja', 'id_unit_kerja', 'unit_kerja_id')
   ->join('aadb_tbl_jenis_form_usulan', 'id_jenis_form_usulan', 'jenis_form')
   ->orderBy('tanggal_usulan', 'DESC')
   ->orderBy('status_proses_id', 'ASC')
   ->where('pegawai_id', Auth::user()->pegawai_id)
   ->get();
```

I try to use with('usulanServis'), but it's doesn't worked too.

```
public function usulanServis() {
    return $this->hasMany(UsulanServis::class,'form_usulan_id', 'id_form_usulan');
}
```

Comment: You should provide more info about Database table contained datas, what  kind of error it is showing ?

Comment: Oh sorry, ok I've updated my question to add Database. No errors are displayed, it's just that the data isn't showing. But, in my file local the data it's showing. I don't know why in web hosting, i can't use hasMany

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but i solved this problem. 
Length of ID (primary key) can't more than 11 if use hasMany method, Length of ID must less than 11.